# Why does the command Jupiter notebook return an error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I try to run Jupiter notebook form the command line I get the following error:

"Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found."

I have Anaconda installed and can do this from the navigator no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs can help: https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/running.html

On the command prompt run:

```
jupyter notebook
```

(w/o dash)